# Ler arquivo estático com vuejs stand-alone

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Tenho uma aplicação criada com a configuração padrão do VUE-CLI, e nela preciso ler um arquivo json da pasta public.

Após compilada a aplicação com o npm run build, o usuário deve poder trocar esse arquivo json e a aplicação ser esse novo json. Até por isso tenho usado a pasta public, pois os arquivos dessa pasta não são compilados pelo webpack.

Porém como a aplicação é executada stand-alone, sem servidor, eu não consigo ler esse json.

Se uso require ou axios, tenho problema com cors ou falta de permissão. Qual a forma correta de, em uma aplicação off-line, carregar um arquivo json?

Desculpe a falta de formatação, estou do celular. Obrigado.

Comment: o ideal era você subir um servidor com `node/express` referenciando o seu build do vue, ai sim você vai conseguir ler o arquivo `json` com o `axios`

Comment: Pois é, fiz isso e funcionou inclusive rs. O problema é que essa página é exibida dentro de um aplicativo Windows, ele é aberto dentro de uma webview como um arquivo estático, então não tenho essa possibilidade. =(

Comment: Complementando a resposta, a aplicação gera um json e então abre a página na webview, que exibe os elementos desse json.

Comment: então não entendi muito bem, dentro de uma webview ( então é um app de celular ? ). Você só consegue trabalhar off-line? Porque senão você pode subir um servidor com esse arquivo json e consultar via api, ou melhor via requisição ajax ou axios

Comment: você já tentou usar jquery `$.getJSON`?

Comment: É um aplicativo Windows, feito em wpf. Eu tenho uma janela com um webview do chromium embutido. É como um webview de celular. 

É o mesmo efeito que você ir na pasta do build e clicar duas vezes pra abrir o índex.html no navegador. 

Vou tentar o jquery chegando em casa.

Comment: Porque você não edita sua pergunta e adiciona tags mais relevantes para sua pergunta (tipo [tag:wpf] ou [tag:webview])? Assim pode ser que alguém que entende do assunto ache sua pergunta.

Comment: É porque a pergunta não tem nada a ver com wpf, o wpf em si só gera o Json, mas o problema é com node e vue mesmo.